# MPIO Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, mpio

I do not see a Multipath IO Role/Feature when I use the "Add Role/Features" wizard on my windows 2016 installation. What am I missing?

Someone kindly help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yj3I.png)

Comment: It's a feature, not a role.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at Features, what you are looking at is Roles. It's the next option down in the stages list on the left hand side of the page beneath where it says Select Server Role.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. SILLY me. The completely changed UI (From 2008 R2 to 2016) threw me completely off guard. I am trying to select this as the correct answer but the site tells me to wait for 5 minutes more. :(